# Why does this not error out

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working with mysql and php and I'm attempting to test the error handling of a call, but I can't figure out why this doesn't give an error.  I'm executing the following line:

```
if (! mysql_query("UPDATE Accounts SET disabled='0' WHERE id='15'")) { ... }
```

Here's the scenario... There is a table called 'Accounts', but there isn't a record with an id of 15 (which is the primary key).  I have tried this from the command line and via a web browser, but this line executes without problems.  I checked the php manual for this and here's a quote from their pages:

```
For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.
```

Why is this not generating an error? Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: An update that results in no changes is not an error.

Comment: Your statement doesn't update any rows, but that's not considered an error. It executed successfully because there were no errors like "undefined column", "table doesn't exist", "can't connect", etc. There are situations where you want to issue an update against rows matching the `WHERE` clause and if the update doesn't find anything then it's OK.

Comment: Thanks for the input gang, I'll refactor the code to take this into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

The query is not failing.

Just because the ID doesn't exist, doesn't mean that the query fails. Mysql successfully looked for the record, found none, and didn't apply any action. This is much different that what the !mysql_query statement suggests. That implies that mysql was unable to run your command.

Here your command ran successfully, just didn't affect your table due to the nonexistent row.

Answer (score 1):

Your query will update no record.
This is not an error, it happens every time the conditions in the `WHERE` clause are not met.

There are many ways to cause your query to fail. One of them would be to use a non-existing field:

```
UPDATE Accounts SET blablabla='0' WHERE id='15'
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between an empty result set, and an error. A query which results in no changes is NOT an error, it's simply a valid result that happens to be empty, e.g.

this can never return anything:

```
mysql> select now() from dual where 1=0;
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

but is still not an error. It's just an empty set. By comparison, this will always return one row:

```
mysql> select now() from dual where 1=1;
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2013-05-03 09:51:19 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and then there's errors. This will not return an empty set, because the query itself failed at the parser level:

```
mysql> select now() from dual where abc=def;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'abc' in 'where clause'
```